# Creating new data table to SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I have a question about creating an application. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with SQL Server Compact 4.0

I'm currently writing an application which requires unspecified numbers of data table. For each new customer, I would like to maintain a data table.

If I'm adding new customer named "Stephanie" to the application it should create a data table named `Stephanie` with specified default columns to database.

Is that possible to create an application with self data table creating to a `.sdf` database file?

Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: When you say data table are you referring to a Table in your Database or an ADO.net DataTable that resides in memory? You would not create a table in a database for every Customer. You have a Customer table and add records for each customer.

Comment: No.  When you add a customer you should be adding *rows* into existing tables.

Comment: Probably not a good design.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do this in the first place? This is not how a database is supposed to work. Anyways, there you go with the query:

```
CREATE TABLE Anna(
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255) 
);
```

Refer here for detailed instructions on how to implement the query: [Create database file (.sdf) if doesn't exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964412/create-database-file-sdf-if-doesnt-exists)

Answer (score 0):

DataSet can hold an unlimited number of DataTables.

```
            var ds = new DataSet();

        var dataTable = new DataTable("DataTable");
        var stringCol = new DataColumn("String Column", typeof(string));
        var intCol = new DataColumn("Integer Column", typeof(int));
        var decimalCol = new DataColumn("Decimal Column", typeof(decimal));

        dataTable.Columns.AddRange(new [] {stringCol, intCol, decimalCol});
        var newRow = new object[]
        {
            "String item",
            1,
            100.08m
        };
        dataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);

        ds.Tables.Add(dataTable);

        var row = ds.Tables["DataTable"].Rows[0];
        var stringRowValue = row["String Column"];
        var intRowValue = row["Integer Column"];
        var decimalRowValue = row["Decimal Column"];
        Console.WriteLine($"String value: {stringRowValue}\nInteger value: {intRowValue}\nDecimal Value: {decimalRowValue}");

        var rowArr = new DataRow[ds.Tables["DataTable"].Rows.Count];
        ds.Tables["DataTable"].Rows.CopyTo(rowArr, 0);

        var list = rowArr.ToList();

        foreach (DataRow rowitem in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\nFrom List: String value: {rowitem["String Column"]}\nInteger value: {rowitem["String Column"]}\nDecimal Value: {rowitem["String Column"]}");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```